# SwiftUI - passing an array to a function

Tags: swiftui

I'm trying to create a simple app that keeps count of how buttons in a list of clothing items have received more than 5 taps.

I've tried using the code below, but keep getting the error "*Cannot convert value of type 'ContentView.clothing' to expected argument type 'Int'*" in the line `if clothes[i].taps >= 5`.

I feel like somehow this might be related to the fact that I've tried to pass a whole `struct` as a parameter of the `func`. Perhaps I'm not meant to do this?

Any guidance much appreciated!

```
import SwiftUI



struct ContentView: View {
    
    struct clothing {
        var type: String
        var taps: Int
    }

    @State var currentClothes = [
        clothing(type: "tshirt", taps: 0),
        clothing(type: "dress", taps: 0)
    ]

    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{

            List{
            
            ForEach(0..<currentClothes.count) { i in
                Button("\(currentClothes[i].type)") {
                    self.currentClothes[i].taps += 1
                    print(currentClothes)
                }
                    
                }
            }
            Text("\(tapCount(clothes: currentClothes))")
        }
    }
    
    func tapCount(clothes: [clothing]) -> Int {

        var total = 0
        for i in clothes {
            if clothes[i].taps >= 5
            {total += 1}
         }
        
         return total
        

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be

```
for i in clothes {
    if i.taps >= 5
    {total += 1}
}
```

not

```
for i in clothes {
    if clothes[i].taps >= 5
    {total += 1}
}
```

because you are looping over `clothes`, not `clothes.count` or something. `i` is a `clothing`, not an `Int`.

As a side note, try to keep your classes and structs Uppercased. `clothing` would be better off as `Clothing`.

Comment: Thank you! I was close it seems!

Comment: @FPL you were! I added a note on naming conventions btw.